# WordPress: CSS property getting cancelled out?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

**In my page.php I am trying to output the featured image in `.page-wrapper` div and display using  `style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>') !important;"` on top of the page (Inline css)**

**The problem** is it keeps on being crossed out by the browser. It may be because there is a 3rd party plugin and that could be overriding it - so I've tried adding `!important` tag to my property. Not working. And I'm disabled the plugin, no luck. IDEAS??

Link to page: http://radian3.com/events/

Here is the page.php

```
<div class="about-container">
<!--  The POST LOOP -->
    <?php  if(have_posts()) :
              while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                  <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>

                  <div class="page-wrapper" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>') !important;">

                 <b class="about-title"><?php the_title(); ?></b>
                 <!-- <div class="about-icon-wrapper" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')"></div> -->
                 </div>
                 <div class="contact-body-wrapper">
                 <?php the_content(); ?>    
                 </div> 
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php else : 
                            echo '<p>No content found..</p>';

                        endif;         
                    ?>
```

CSS

```
/* single.php  page */
.page-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
/*  background-image: url('../img/about-our-team.jpg') !important;
*/  height: 30rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, its your code in page.php that's doing the overriding.

The image you see crossed out id included in your css file, the one with the emply url the one generated by your code.

Your code isn't returning any image, so you need to fix that. Unless you have $post explicitly defined, it wont have a value here, so $post->ID will be empty. 
You should `use get_the_ID()` inside the loop, i.e.

```
<?php 
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'full' );
if ($thumb){
?>
      <div class="page-wrapper" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')">
<?php 
// rest of your code....
}
```

FYI, you should also check to make sure $thumb has a value - if it doesn't, you could use a default placeholder instead

Comment: Thanks for the answer once again! Btw the themesharper tutorial you've suggested is amazing, going through it!

Comment: Just out of curiosity are you a WordPress developer? Do you also develop eCommerce themes on it as well, if so, do you use WooCommerce framework too? A bit random :)

Comment: Well my background is software engineering but I do some web development & Wordpress development these days. No Woocommerce though. But I have a client who might need it soon, so who knows - I might be asking you for advice one of these days :) And I found that tutorial really helpful too - it was the one that got me up & running in WP coming from a standard HTML & PHP sites (just like yourself by the look of it!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove inline style attribute which sets no image to it but it is overriding css for background image url for `page-wrapper`

You need to remove the following attribute from `page-wrapper` div.

```
style="background-image: url('') !important;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give like this

`background-image: url("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/parallax_image.jpg ");`

Comment: That won't work. Whats `thumb('template_directory')` supposed to be?

Comment: `bloginfo('template_directory')` basically give  active theme’s directory.

Comment: Yes, but whats "thumb"?

Comment: It is also hardcoding the image - the OP wants to use the image returned in $thumb, so if you're suggesting they use `template_directory`, how are you suggesting they get the image from the post?